# Could not resolve archetype

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-luna

I want to create a Java Restful WebService with Maven template `jersey-quickstart-webapp`.

I'm facing the following error:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.23.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.23.1
Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.23.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.23.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
```

I'm using Eclipse Luna, latest version.

Comment: I'm guessing you should have a proxy in you eclipse.

Comment: yes, I'm having a proxy still its not working,I'm in corporate environment here we are using proxy so I'm using that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the proxy in your settings.xml

```
<proxies>
 <proxy>
    <id>example-proxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.example.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

If it still does not work, probably Maven Central is not accessible from within your network. Then you can only ask your admin to unblock it or to mirror it in a company repository.